# How to get openconnect to unmount a partition when VPN closes?

Tags: mount, vpn, nfs, openconnect

I have this entry in my fstab:

```
sc-netapp48.nvidia.com:/vol/scratch9/scratch.securesign_new /home/scratch.securesign_new nfs _netdev,comment=systemd.automount 0 0
```

I'm not sure how this works exactly, but when I'm on the VPN and need to access `/home/scratch.securesign_new`, it magically shows up.

However, when I disconnect from the VPN, it appears that `/home/scratch.securesign_new` is still mounted.  This causes all sorts of problems.  For example, whenever I install a program, the installer tries to access `/home/scratch.securesign_new/.config`, which doesn't exist.

So I need to be able to `umount -l /home/scratch.securesign_new` when the VPN closes.  How do I do that?  I tried adding a script in `/etc/network/if-down.d/`, but that script is not executed when the VPN closes.

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I confirmed that a script in `/etc/network/if-down.d/` does not appear to get called at all when disconnecting from an openconnect vpn.

However `/etc/network/if-post-down.d/` does get called so you can put your script there.  Make sure the permissions on your script are 755.

Comment: I just tried it, and it didn't work.  I also tried putting a test script in /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/, and that didn't do anything either.

Edit: interesting is the output of run-parts: 

# run-parts --test /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant

my script isn't listed.  So something is preventing it from being run, even though it's 755.

Comment: So one thing I just discovered is that I'm impacted by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/debianutils/+bug/38022  I renamed my script from "vpn.sh" to "vpn", and it is now executed.  However, the unmount doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ok, I got it working now, thanks!  I've marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options : Either check for the presence of the `openconnect` process  , or check the IP address for example every 1 second to determine whether we're still on VPN or not.I assumed that the IP address remains the same during an **OpenConnect** session.So this should work :

```
#######   BASED ON THE PRESENCE OF OPENCONNECT   #######

while [ 1 ]
do
    if  [ -n `pgrep openconnect` ] 
         then sudo umount -l /home/scratch.securesign_new
    fi
    sleep 1
done

######   OR BASED ON THE IP ADDRESS   ######

sudo openconnect -u user --passwd-on-stdin vpnserver
sleep 10
vpn_ip=`curl ifconfig.me`
while [ 1 ] 
do
    current_ip=`curl ifconfig.me`
    if [ "$vpn_ip" != "$current_ip" ]
        then sudo umount -l /home/scratch.securesign_new
    fi
    sleep 1
done
```

And feel free to play around with the numbers in front of `sleep`.I added a 10 second delay after starting the VPN service because it might take a while for the VPN connection to actually get started.

And I used the website [ifconfig.me](https://ifconfig.me/) to get the IP address.But it might not be a reliable source of information if you want to use it regularly(I mean it might get down for some reason, I don't know).And if your terminal doesn't send the traffic through OpenConnect(sorry for being so ignorant about that because I don't use that) you have to add this before the **BASED ON THE IP ADDRESS** part of the script:

```
$ export http_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
```

If there's any better solution , I'm glad to hear.

Hope it helps.

Comment: um, openconnect and openvpn are two different things..

Comment: @RobertRiedl Sorry my bad.I didn't get the point correctly.I have to update some parts of my answer,but the **Based on the IP address** part still should work.However thanks for constructive feedback :) . I updated my post.